# Model is null in when Post data to controller Asp.Net Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a form which is having a text area, when I enter characters which count less than 200, then working fine. If the character limit is more than 200 my whole model is getting null when I submit the form.

So I have added max length attribute as of now but my requirement is to enter as maximum character. My code snippet as follows

Model as

```
[BindProperty]
 [Required(ErrorMessage ="notes are required")]
 [MaxLength(200)]
 public string Notes { get; set; }
```

My controller as follows

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("notes")]
public async Task<JsonResult> AddNotes(ProfileReviewNotesViewModel model)
{
   var response = await this.profileModelBuilder.SaveNots(model, UserId);
   return Json(response);
}
```

Kindly help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `ModelState.IsValid`. Basically if the model has error, the property does not get filled, Instead `ModelState.IsValid = false` and ModelState contains errors.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("notes")]
public async Task<JsonResult> AddNotes(ProfileReviewNotesViewModel model)
{
   if ( !ModelState.IsValid )
       return <bad request> //here


   var response = await this.profileModelBuilder.SaveNots(model, UserId);
   return Json(response);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I got the error as Failed to read the request form. Form value length limit 200 exceeded. Is there any way to increase the value length of the form?

Comment: Failed to read the request form. Form value length limit 200 exceeded

Comment: I solved the problem finally. We need to use enctype="multipart/form-data".. Thank you so much for helping me to identify the root cause